# Image shifting while displaying border around listbox item wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listbox, border

I am using a listbox to display images. When a listbox item is selected it displays a border around the image. Instead of displaying border around the image it shifts the image towards right.

Listbox style:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=UriSource}" 
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        Width="639" Height="530">
                     </Image>
                 </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
     <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <WrapPanel />
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" 
          Value="Disabled"/>
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" 
          Value="Disabled"/>

       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
           Value="Left"/>
       <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" 
           Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

List box item style:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                   <Border x:Name="Bd"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <ContentPresenter  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource BorderColor}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="12" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="639"  />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="530"  />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource BorderColor}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="12" />
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="639" />
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="530" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your `ListBoxItem` style, you're changing the border's thickness, from `0` in the normal case, to `12` when the item is selected. This shifts the content by 12pt.

You have several of possible solutions here, here are two possibilities:

- Always use a 12pt border, but use a `Transparent` or `{x:Null}` brush in the unselected state
- Use a `12` margin on your `ContentPresenter`, and set it to `0` in the triggers

Comment: When I add a transparent border or margin there is a spacing introduced in  images on the sides. I always want to images to have a total width of 1280 and height 530 .I am just displaying 2 images on 1280 * 720 screen.

Answer (score 0):

Used Layout transform instead of using Render transform.
 Set Margin="-2,0,-2,0"
 Padding="-1,0,-1,0" for listbox.
and